# maven does not run scala tests through jenkins

Tags: scala, maven, jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMqRT.png)When I run scala tests through Jenkins and maven, it gives me following output. I am not sure why it is not picking my scala test which is under src/test/scala.
The output in jenkins' console output is as follows-

```
[INFO] [scalatest:test {execution: test}]
[36mRun starting. Expected test count is: 0[0m
[32mDiscoverySuite:[0m
[36mRun completed in 905 milliseconds.[0m
[36mTotal number of tests run: 0[0m
[36mSuites: completed 1, aborted 0[0m
[36mTests: succeeded 0, failed 0, ignored 0, pending 0[0m
[32mAll tests passed.[0m
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOLBE.png)

Above is my folder structure.
PFB my pom.xml-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hsbc.ftp.bigdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>rpf</artifactId>
  <version>${rpf.release.version}</version>

  <distributionManagement>

        <repository>
            <id>dsnexus-releases</id>
            <name>Nexus Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://dsnexus.uk.hibm.hsbc:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>


        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>dsnexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Nexus Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://dsnexus.uk.hibm.hsbc:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>

  </distributionManagement>

  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.version>2.10.5</scala.version>



  </properties>

  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
           <exclude>**/*.scala</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>                            
                        </goals>                        
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.hsbc.ftp.rpf.driver.RPFDriver</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </configuration>
</plugin>


<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
     <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
     <junitxml>.</junitxml>
     <filereports>WDFTestSuite.txt</filereports>
     <skipTests>false</skipTests>
   </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

      </plugins>
  </build>


  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodaExt</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
          <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>                   
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

could you please suggest how can I have my scala test executed?

Thanks
Abhishek Somani

Comment: were you able to run the scalatests in your local?, I have been running scalatests in jenkins with the same plugin (`scalatest-maven-plugin`) that you are using - https://github.com/nihil-os/stream-driver/blob/kinesis-stream/pom.xml#L199

Comment: no ...same issue but there are some access issues in my local machine that's why I presumed it should work from Jenkins. But no luck!

Comment: It says `completed 1`, do you even have any tests inside the testclass?

Comment: I suggest you to try this example to make sure its working - https://github.com/nihil-os/conifers-specs/blob/master/pom.xml#L104, its very simple example, just git clone it and run `mvn clean test`

Comment: no testclass....its just /BRPF/src/test/scala/StandardJoinUDFSpec.scala

Comment: That is a test class, I am asking do you have any tests inside that class? Based on log it seems empty

Comment: tried running github project mentioned by you...getting this error...[ERROR] Plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its depend
ncies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.alchim3
.maven:scala-maven-plugin:jar:3.2.2: Could not transfer artifact net.alchim31.m
ven:scala-maven-plugin:pom:3.2.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org
maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: yes it says completed 1 but it does not run the test cases.

Comment: weird `net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2` is the plugin I use for scala compilation. And, can you post whats inside the test class you use?

Comment: I am not able to post It here as it is going out of limit tats why I have inserted image of the contents of test class in my original question.

Comment: do we really need this plugin for scala compilation as we are able to compile and upload the application jar file to nexus. We just want to run the scala tests and I think scalatest-maven-plugin is meant for that.

Comment: Regarding failure to download `net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2`, do you have proxy thing in your network. Try `ping repo.maven.apache.org` to make sure network is fine. And `scala-maven-plugin` for scala classes compilation in `src/main/scala`, but at least you will know scalatests are running in your local.

Comment: cant ping repo.maven.apache.org! i am already using maven-scala-plugin and maven-jar-plugin to compile ,my scala code and upload the jar file to nexus. I just want to run my scala test cases. did you check the contents of my test class?

Comment: I did and figured out you are missing `testCompile goal`, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `scala-maven-plugin` plugin to be able to run scalatests using maven. I tried your scenario, and it works only with `scala-maven-plugin` with `testCompile` goal.

> The scala-maven-plugin (previously maven-scala-plugin - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-tools/maven-scala-plugin/2.15.2) is used for
>   compiling/testing/running/documenting scala code in maven.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>false</parallel>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                <filereports>test-suite.log</filereports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Or since you already have `maven-scala-plugin`, just add `testCompile` to your execution goal.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I know http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin mentions only `scalatest-maven-plugin` which is not true. `scalatest-maven-plugin` tries to discover the tests but does run anything.

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you sooo much Prayag! It atleast detected the test though it got failed but atleast didn skip this time!